# Creating DCOM Client in .NET 6 with C# for 3rdParty OPC DCOM server

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, dcom

I created a client in C# in MS Visual Studio 2022 (.NET 6) using the third-party provided API.dll file — my code compiles without any error.

The purpose of the client above is to connect to a server, which uses DCOM and OPC technologies. I have never worked with these technologies.

I successfully built my OPC server and client using OPC packages I found online. OPC server client development was straightforward.

I can not use these packages to build the client's connection to this particular Server using DCOM technology.

When I build the client with the API.dll file provided by the 3rd party and try to connect to Server, I get the following error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {5044B1D9-6D96-47CD-9DD2-A8A06EB99B6C} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I was advised to register my application dll file using `regsvr32` and

```
regasm myClient.dll /tlb:myClient.tlb
```

Both commands failed, indicating that it was not the correct dll file.
I did run `regsvr32` on the `thirdpary.dll` API file, and it worked without any problem. Even after that, when I ran my client application, it failed with the same error.

I can not understand why I should register a client DCOM application.
Please advise.

Here is my code

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  <RegisterForComInterop>true</RegisterForComInterop> 
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="OPCBRIDGELib">
      <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
      <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
      <Guid>f38628bd-c890-40fb-9098-110a235f9252</Guid>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <Isolated>false</Isolated>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


        public Monitor()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Alarm Viewer Console Program");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 'Exit' to close the program.");

        // Initialize the subscription
        Subscription oSubscription = new Subscription();
       // Subscription  oSubscription;
        // Main loop
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter Server Name: ");
            string? serverName = Console.ReadLine();

            if (serverName != null && serverName.ToLower() == "exit")
            {
                break;
            }

            try
            {
                if (serverName != null)




                    ConnectToServer(serverName, oSubscription);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        // Disconnect and clean up
        DisconnectFromServer(oSubscription);
        oSubscription = null;

        Console.WriteLine("Program closed.");




    }

    void ConnectToServer(string serverName, Subscription oSubscription)
    {
        // Initialize the subscription if it's null
        if (oSubscription == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("oSubscription is null");

            // oSubscription = new Subscription();
        }

        oSubscription = new Subscription();

        // Connect to the server
        oSubscription.Server = serverName;

        EventGroups oAvailableGroups;
        EventGroups oGroups = new EventGroups();
        EventGroup? oGroup = new EventGroup();

        oAvailableGroups = oSubscription.GetAvailableGroups();

        foreach (EventGroup group in oAvailableGroups)
        {
            oGroups.Add(group);
        }

        oSubscription.MaximumPriority = 9;
        oSubscription.MinimumPriority = 1;
        oSubscription.CheckEnabled = 1;
        oSubscription.CheckInterval = 10;
        oSubscription.ConnectAttempts = 1;
        oSubscription.ConnectInterval = 1;
        oSubscription.NotifyOnFailure = 0;
        oSubscription.Activate();
        oSubscription.Refresh();

        Console.WriteLine("Connected to server.");
        Console.WriteLine("Listening for alarm events...");

        // Keep the program running until the user types 'Exit'
        while (true)
        {
            // You can add any additional logic here if needed
            // For example, you can handle events received from the server
            // by implementing the event handler oSubscription_OnEvent

            // Sleep for a while to avoid consuming too much CPU
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }






    void DisconnectFromServer(Subscription oSubscription)
    {
        // Disconnect from the server
        if (oSubscription != null)
        {
            oSubscription.Deactivate();
            Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from server.");
        }
    }

    private void oSubscription_OnEvent(IEventNotification pNotification)
    {
        // Handle event notifications here
        // Display the alarm event in the console
        Console.WriteLine("Alarm Event:");
        Console.WriteLine($"  Message: {pNotification.Message}");
        Console.WriteLine($"  Alarm: {(pNotification.Alarm == 1 ? "Yes" : "No")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"  Active: {(pNotification.Active == 1 ? "Yes" : "No")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"  Processed: {(pNotification.Processed == 1 ? "Yes" : "No")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"  Acknowledged: {(pNotification.Acknowledged == 1 ? "Yes" : "No")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"  Cookie: {pNotification.Cookie}");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [Classic OPC core components](https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/samples-and-tools-classic/core-components/). You can use any third-party library, but this installation package will register all Classic OPC-related components in the system.

Start from [Matrikon OPC Explore](https://www.matrikonopc.com/products/opc-desktop-tools/opc-explorer.aspx) (as an example) to test connection with the OPC Server. After successful testing you can proceed to debug your application.

Then your next step is to build your app based on [.NET API Sample Client Source Code](https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/samples-and-tools-classic/net-api-sample-client-source-code/). It will allow you to create a good OPC DA (HDA, A&E) client application.

Comment: Hi , Thank you. I installed "Classic OPC Core Components" still same error.  To make it clear what is happening. I am using MS Visual Studio 2022 .NET 6 C# to develop a 32 bit Console application with 3rd Party API.dll. Program compiles and run. As soon as I enter the name of server it has to connect it will come with the following error.    Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {5044B1D9-6D96-47CD-9DD2-A8A06EB99B6C} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Comment: Did you perform the test with Matrikon OPC Explorer (or another similar tool)?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for getting back. Yes, it did work. But my application won't work.  I am wondering  whether I am missing some thing. I have posted the code now.

Comment: Look at the updated answer.